# How would you solve $3^x = 2x + 3$ using the Lambert $W$ function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

Could someone provide a solution to the equation
$$
3^x = 2x+3. 
$$

Our teacher told us to solve it graphically, but I was curious what the exact answers might be and just plugged it into Wolfram Alpha and saw that the two solutions came from the principle and the $-1$ branch of the Lambert $W$ function.

I am familiar with the "function" and how it is the inverse "function" of the function $xe^x$, but whatever transformations I tried I just couldn't obtain the wolfram alpha solution.

Any help, hints or even a solution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
3^x&=2x+3\\
e^{\log (3) x}&=2(x+\frac{3}{2})\\
-\frac{\log (3)}{2}&=-\log (3)(x+\frac{3}{2})e^{-\log (3) x}\\
-\frac{\log (3)}{2}e^{-\frac{3}{2}\log(3)}&=-\log (3)(x+\frac{3}{2})e^{-\log (3) (x+\frac{3}{2})}\\
\end{align*}
Now the RHS is in the form $ye^y$. So
\begin{align*}
-\log (3) (x+\frac{3}{2})&=W\left(-\frac{\log (3)}{2}e^{-\frac{3}{2}\log(3)}\right)\\
x+\frac{3}{2}&=-\frac{1}{\log(3)}W\left(-\frac{\log (3)}{2}e^{-\frac{3}{2}\log(3)}\right)\\
x&=-\frac{1}{\log(3)}W\left(-\frac{\log (3)}{2}e^{-\frac{3}{2}\log(3)}\right)-\frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much! @Joshua Tilley

Answer (score 0):

Since @Joshua Tilley gave the detailed steps, consider the more general case of
$$a^x=bx+c$$The solution is
$$x=-\frac c b-\frac {W(t)}{\log(a)}\quad \text{where} \quad t=-\frac{\log (a)}{b}\,a^{\frac{b}{c}}$$

In the real domain, we must have $t \ge -\frac 1e$.

You can also consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=a^x-bx-c$$ The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{\log \left(\frac{b}{\log (a)}\right)}{\log (a)}$$ So, if
$$f(x_*)=\frac{b-b \log \left(\frac{b}{\log (a)}\right)-c \log (a)}{\log (a)}$$ is negative, there are two solutions on the left and right sides of $x_*$.

You can have a rough idea of where are the solution using Taylor series
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*)\,(x-x_*)^2+ O((x-x_*)^3)$$

For your specific case, this would give $x_1=-0.892$ and $x_2=1.983$ while the solutions are $-1.392$ and $1.686$.